# Why is my HttpOnly cookie not stored in the browser for cross site domains?

Tags: spring-boot, security, cors, cross-domain, httponly

I would like to save my HttpOnly cookie that I get from the backend in the browser. However, this is not happening and I don't know why.

In my Spring Boot (Java) app, I added the HttpOnly cookie in the AuthenticationController to the login request:

```
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<User> authenticate(AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {

        // Authenticate the user and retrieve the JWT token.
        String jwtToken = authenticationService.authenticateAndGetJwtToken(authenticationRequest);

        // Set the token in the response header as an HttpOnly cookie.
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE,
                "sid=" + jwtToken + "; Path=/;  Max-Age=9999999;  HttpOnly; SameSite=none");

        // Retrieve user data for the authenticated user.
        User user = authenticationService.getUserByIdentifier(authenticationRequest.getUseridentifier());

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(user);
    }
```

Here are my CorsFilter settings:

```
   @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // set request header-informations for cross-site
        // Unfortunately, the settings are currently not working
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Withcredentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "99999999");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, xsrf-token, withCredentials, includeSubDomains, Accept-Encoding");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        response.addHeader("Cache-control", "no-store, no-cache");
        response.addHeader("Vary", "Cookie");

        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why my HttpOnly cookie is not being saved on login in my Angular app? The login request itself works. Only the HttpOnly cookie is not saved. Please let me know if you want me to provide more info.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE 1)

```
headers.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE,"sid=" + jwtToken + "; Path=/;  Max-Age=9999999; Domain=http://localhost:8100  Secure, HttpOnly; SameSite=lax");
```

Comment: `withCredentials` is an _option_ to set in XMLHttpRequest/ fetch code that makes the request, not an HTTP header.

Comment: Could you maybe back this up with a link? I can not find much to xmlhttprequest

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: Set domain on the cookie so the browser knows it needs to include the cookie in the request? Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; Domain=<domain-value>

Comment: `SameSite=None` also requires `Secure` in Chromium-based browsers (Chrome, Brave, Edge, etc.).

Comment: @MarekPuchalski No, that's is not what the `Domain` attribute is for. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#domaindomain-value

Comment: @jub0bs But this is only valid for SSL encrypted pages or? Currently my APP runs on hppt and not on hppts

Comment: Correct: only a secure Web origin (i.e. whose scheme is `https`, typically) can set a cookie marked `Secure`. If that's not your case, you cannot mark your cookie `SameSite=None`.

Comment: But there is a way to store the httpOnly cookie without SLL in the browser? I've been sitting for days to solve this problem

Comment: The value of your cookie's `HttpOnly` flag is orthogonal to the issue at hand. The fact is that Chrome won't let you set a cookie with `SameSite=None` without `Secure`, and browsers in general won't allow an insecure Web origin to set a `Secure` cookie. If you can't obtain a TLS certificate, your only option is to adopt some other value for your cookie's `SameSite` attribute. Perhaps `Lax` would be viable...

Comment: But the easiest thing would be to just bite the bullet and get a TLS cert for your domain. And doing so is free!